# webview host application in android

Tags: android, webview

I am a beginner. When I start to make an app with webview.

I saw on docs that https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)

Give the host application a chance to take control when a URL is about to be loaded in the current WebView.

I am weak in Englis but I know what is hosting. but I don't get what is host application, why it calls like that?

1) Is host application means a web browser or webview in my app?

2) It should be helpful how shouldoverrideurlloading works with webview and browser.

3) return true will open a web browser??

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    return handleUri(view, uri);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
    return handleUri(view, uri);
}
```

and handleUri method

```
private boolean handleUri(WebView view, Uri uri) {
    final String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    final String host = uri.getHost();
    // Based on some condition you need to determine if you are going to load the url
    // in your web view itself or in a browser.
    // You can use `host` or `scheme` or any part of the `uri` to decide.
    if (scheme.startsWith("http:") || scheme.startsWith("https:")) {
        view.loadUrl(uri.getPath());
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: in docs, says calling view.loadUrl() and return true is not the right way.

Comment: That is correct. When using webview you have full control over everything.  You have to emulate a browser. So like if you wanted to seriously log a user in a website.  You would input the username and password into the input boxes and submit.  Then the url actually goes through several URLs before arriving at the final page. Basically load url and then returning true is like saying load this url and then stop loading this URL and stop. Err true will override a url that is passed to it load that url then start loading url. False just loads the url that is passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

When using webview you use shouldOverrideUrlLoading to enter a specific url(the one you intend the user to see). This method also will,  with some more advanced coding used when scrapping data from web pages, allow you to collect the html data and possible modify or utilize the html document code in creative ways. Then displaying the webview to the user when your ready.

Ps. Heads up depending on which api your minimum is set at you have to use it differently.  There are some tutorials on google searches but most are outdated. This is not a common practice. More often than not apps use an api provided by a url and then display the data or intended visuals.

Comment: bro..actually what is host application here means?

Comment: Host application here means your app that your coding that contains the webview. I could be mistaken. But I believe it means do you want to do something with the intended url in your app first or just display the url in view.

Comment: yes, I want to display webpage in webview, but "host application" and "webview" word using in docs got me confused.

Comment: true causes the current WebView to abort loading the URL in docs. but in my webview nothing happens? why is that?

Comment: Host application is your app or activity, the webview is like a web browser like chrome so to speak. So abort the loading url means stop loading this url in your webview. Do something with url data and then at that point it gets complicated because you build your "browser" from there. False says just use the default browser chosen for the android device to load and display url. That is about as lamen terms I can come up with.

Comment: In docs, it says "returning false causes the WebView to continue loading the URL as usual" but u said false says just use the default browser.

Comment: Exactly, at it's most basic sense its saying use false if you just want to load the url and display the page. No extra stuff just load it. I was just attempting to help you understand how it works, in a way. It technically won't load the default browser you still have to choose in back buttons and any functionality you want.  But using false says take over leading this page for me.  Use google chrome browserer and open the developer screen.  I think it's like f11 or something like that and play with that.  You can see how much is taken care of that you don't see.